# rcpp named numeric matrix

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp

With Rcpp I couldn't figure out a way to address a matrix by column names in the C++ code.  There doesn't seem to be overloads for the various Matrix functions that let you address rows or columns by name as specified in R.  The use case I have for this is where you have a table of values from an sql query etc where each column is named.

Here is the obviously incomplete and not ideal work around I came up with:

```
class NamedNumericMatrix {
public:
    NamedNumericMatrix(SEXP m)
    {
      M=NumericMatrix(m);
      List dimnames = M.attr("dimnames");
      vector<string> colnames = dimnames[1];
      for(int i = 0; i<colnames.size(); i++){
        map<string, int>::iterator it = colNameIndex.find(colnames[i]);
        if(it != colNameIndex.end()){
          throw std::invalid_argument("duplicate colname found");
        }
        colNameIndex[colnames[i]] = colNameIndex.size()-1;
      }
    }
    double GetValue(int row, string col){
      map<string, int>::iterator it = colNameIndex.find(col);
      if(it == colNameIndex.end()){
        throw std::invalid_argument("col name not found");
      }
      return M(row, it->second);
    }
  int nrow(){
    return M.nrow();
  }
  int ncol(){
    return M.ncol();
  }
private:
    NumericMatrix M;
    map<string, int> colNameIndex;
};
```

My question is, is there an easier way to do this with Rcpp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `colnames()` which returns a character vector:

```
R> cppFunction("int showme(NumericMatrix M) { print(colnames(M)); return 0; }")
R> showme(matrix(1:9,3,dimnames=list(NULL, c("a1", "b2", "c3"))))
[1] "a1" "b2" "c3"
[1] 0
R>
```

Oh, sorry, re-reading:  you mean *index* by name?  We treat a matrix mostly as a numerical object.  You can index `List` and `DataFrame` by name.  For a matrix you may have answered your question with the above.

Comment: this makes sense, probably it would be more appropriate for me to store this type of data in a DataFrame

Comment: I think so too.  From the db, you may also get different types which does not always suit a matrix.